# Recursive function is not working in code-igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using a recursive function in codeigniter but is not working properly while returning the `std` class object  but if i am using `print_r()` then `print_r()` is printing exactly what i want.

I am not getting any warning error message.

```
public function get_base_id($id){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `m_ecommerce_category` WHERE status ='0' and id = '$id'");
    $data = $query->row();
    if($data->parent != 0 ){
        $this->get_base_id($data->parent);
    }else{
        //print_r($data);
        return  $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `return` your recursive call:

```
if($data->parent != 0 ){
    return $this->get_base_id($data->parent);
}else{
    //print_r($data);
    return  $data;
}
```